# $f,g \in R(T)$ such that $\hat{f} \cdot n^{2/3} = \hat{g}$ prove that $f$'s Fourier series converges absolutely.

Tags: calculus, summation, fourier-analysis, solution-verification

Can someone help me by checking my solution. Is there a shorter More elegant solution ?(i'm almost sure you can some how express  $f$'s Fourier series using $|\hat{g}|^2$ + constant, i saw someone do it in few easy manipulations but was never able to reproduce it myself)

$f,g \in R(T)$ (integrable periodic functions with period $2\pi$) such that $\hat{f} \cdot n^{2/3} = \hat{g}$ prove that $f$'s Fourier series converges absolutely.

$$(S_{N}f)(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-N}^N \hat{g}(n) \cdot \frac{e^{int}}{n^{2/3}}$$

$$|\hat{g'(n)}|^2 = n^2|\hat{g(n)}|^2$$

$$\sum n^2|\hat{g}(n)|^2 < \infty$$

$$|\hat{g(n)}| = |\hat{g(n)}| \cdot n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{2} \cdot(|\hat{g(n)}|^2n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2})\cdot n$$

the last Inequality is just means Inequality. Now finally

$$\sum|\hat{g(n)}| \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot \sum n^2|\hat{g(n)}|^2 + |\hat{g(0)}| + \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty$$

so

$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{g}(n)| < \infty$$

moreover $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{e^{int}}{n^{2/3}}| = 0$ now we can use dirichlet's test for convergence of functions series to finish the proof.

Is it correct ?

I'm almost sure that you can solve this by expressing $f$'s Fourier series with $(\hat{g}(n))^2$  and then using parseval's theorem to prove that the series converges .

Comment: You don't have a premise that $\sum \lvert \hat{g}(n)\rvert < +\infty$. You should look at Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Boris Why do you state $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{g}(n)| < \infty$?

Comment: sorry for omitting detailes about $\sum|\hat{g}(n)| < \infty$ i didnt remember the proof but just that i heard it as a conclusion in one of the lectures . i added the proof

Comment: What is $R(T)$?

Comment: integrable periodic functions with period 2π

Comment: How do you justify that $\sum\limits_nn^2|\hat{g}(n)|^2\lt\infty$?

Comment: $\sum n^2 |\hat{g(n)}|^2 = \sum|\hat{g'(n)}|^2 < \infty$ (by parseval's theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $\sum|\hat f(n)|<\infty$.
$$
\sum|\hat f(n)|=\sum n^{-2/3}|\hat g(n)|\le\Bigl(\sum n^{-4/3}\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\sum|\hat g(n)|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}<\infty
$$
since $4/3>1$ and $g$ is Riemann-integrable, and hence in $L^2$.

Comment: How do we show that if $g\in L^1(T)$, it is in $L^2(T)$? The other direction is trivial since $T$ has finite measure.

Comment: @robjohn I understood $R(T)$ as Riemann integrable functions (because of the $R$). If It means $L^1$, then you are right, and there is no reason why $g$ should be in $L^2$.

Comment: If we're relying on $g\in L^\infty(T)$, then sure, $g\in L^1(T)\implies g\in L^2(T)\implies \hat{g}\in\ell^2$. Perhaps you are correct; otherwise, there would be no way to show that $\hat{f}\in\ell^1$.